# I need another Top new questions in my email subscription

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

Is there a way to manage Top new questions in my email subscription? I really don't need questions and information about C+. I need PHP and JavaScript!

Comment: Create your own [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/390844/phpjs). See this answer of mine how to create/edit one:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224536/add-new-tags-to-an-existing-filter-on-stack-exchange/224557#224557